# How is it possible that this Query takes so much time without using much resources?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I ran SQL Server Profiler trace (duration on batch complete) and found one really long running query. These are the utilization statistics for the top five longest running queries:

```
Count   Duration    CPU     Reads   Writes
1       1237757030  608     47979   10
14695   358668961   355928  4818709 315
3501    48323496    43705   625474  17 
75883   46373094    45250   8526977 127
34      35394031    10200   2461621 0
```

The first one runs nearly 3 times longer than the second, even though the second has a much larger cumulative CPU time and number of reads than the first one. How could this be, or how can I find out more about what is happening here?

Comment: If your running SQL profiler, you should be able to get at the original SQL query that's being run. If you can look at that surely that should provide an insight? if so paste it into the question.

Comment: You could try to look at the queries execution plan to get a better idea of what the query is doing and why it is taking so long.

Comment: LongerDuration+LessCPU-LessReads-LessWrites may be from one (or more) Locks that the query was waiting to be released.

Comment: Even when you isolate this down to the query and look at its code and maybe still don't find anything, it could have been subject to a long I/O. Event 833 won't populate for these until 15 seconds have passed, which is an eternity considering the optimal read time is anywhere from 10-50ms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually this is caused by some kind resource contention. In other words, your query is idle while waiting for locks to be released (blocking), data to be read from disk, waiting for threads to complete their work etc.

It's a deep subject, but I would recommend starting by looking at your wait stats.

To get an idea of the cumulitive wait stats, look at sys.dm_os_wait_stats. From BOL:

> “Specific types of wait times during query execution can indicate
>   bottlenecks or stall points within the query. Similarly, high wait
>   times, or wait counts server wide can indicate bottlenecks or hot
>   spots in interaction query interactions within the server instance.”

You can also run your query and attempt to identify issues with blocking. Here's a good article on the subject.

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-tools/how-to-identify-blocking-problems-with-sql-profiler/

These are a few areas to look but, honestly there are so many variables that, short of having access to your server, it is incredibly difficult to anything beyond offer guesses and suggestions on where you could look.